# find the last created subdirectory in a directory of 500k subdirs

Tags: bash

I have a folder with some 500k subfolders - and I would like to find the last directory which was added to this folder. I am having to do this due to a power failure issue :(

I dont excatly know when the power failed, so using this:

```
find . -type d -mmin -360 -print
```

which I beleive is the last 360 minutes? However, gives me results which I am not exactly sure of.

Shortly speaking, I would like to get the last directory which was created within this folder.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Would writing a short program (for example in C) that processes the output of `find` be an option?

Comment: If I understand rightly Linux doesn't store creation date, only last modified date.

Comment: @Kendle Depends on the filesystem. Most of the popular ones do store birth time these days.

Comment: @Kendle That's true for modern Linux versions; however, the "ctime" time contains the time of the last `chmod`, `chown` or creation of a hard link to the directory. If the OP did not do any of these operations, this is the time of creation. The "mtime" field is changed whenever a file in the directory is created. So if the last operation before the crash was the creation of a file in one of the directories, `ls -t` would recognize the parent directory as the "lastest one".

Comment: I would create a program that takes file names from the standard input. The program would call `stat()` for each file and check the `st_ctime` field. The program would "remember" the name of the newest file (the highest value of `st_ctime`). Then I would call the program like this: `find . -type d | ~/myProgram`. Please note that in the last second before the crash multiple directories may have been created so multiple files may have the same `st_ctime` value (you cannot automatically find out which of them is the latest in this case) ...

Comment: ... This approach has the advantage that only two processes are running. (Using `find ... -exec ...` you would start a new process for every directory which is a lot of overhead (time!!) for 500k files.) You could even speed this up by implementing a recursive directory search in your own program. In this case, `stat()` needs only to be called once and the overhead for the pipe is also eliminated.

Comment: @MartinRosenau If you're going the C route, use `nftw()` to walk the directory tree. Don't have to implement the directory tree traversal yourself that way.

Comment: @MartinRosenau seems a bit of an overkill IMO - bit stunned I can get this in a few chars on bash :(

Comment: @JohnJ The slower variant (`find . -type d | myProgram`) would be about 20-30 lines of C code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting :

```
 find . -type d -printf "%C@ %p\n" |sort -n|tail -n1|awk '{print $2}'
```

### Explanation:

#### `find . -type d -printf "%C@ %p\n"`

`find .` start searching from current directory recursively

`-type d` search only directory files

`-printf "%C@ %p\n"` for each directory print its last change time in secs from Unix epoch time including sec fraction, followed by file name with path.

For example: `1648051886.4404644000 /tmp/mc-dudi`

#### `|sort -n|tail -n1`

Sort the result from find as numbers, and print the last row.

#### `awk '{print $2}'`

From last row, print only second field

Comment: Access time? It's pretty common to mount filesystems with noatime to skip tracking that. (Or relatime or a few other possibilities; point being you can't rely on it being accurate)

Comment: this worked! thank you friend - genius stuff.

Comment: using `sort -n` would be more accurate, or else `2.0` (year 1970) will be considered greater than `1648051886.4404644000` (year 2022)

Comment: thanks fixed your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You might try this: it shows your last modification date/time in a sortable manner, and by sorting it, the last entry should be the most recent one:

```
find ./ -exec ls -dils --time-style=long-iso {} \; | sort -k8,9
```

**Edit**: and specific for directories:

```
find ./ -type d -exec ls -dils --time-style=long-iso {} \; | sort -k8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a file system that tracks file creation ('birth' is the usual terminology) times, and GNU versions of the programs used below:

```sh
find . -type d -exec stat --printf '%W\t%n\0' \{\} + | sort -z -k1,1nr | head -1 -z | cut -f 2-
```

This will find all subdirectories of the current working directory, and for each one, print its birth time (The `%W` format field for `stat(1)`) and name (The `%n` format). Those entries are then sorted based on the timestamp, newest first, and the first line is returned minus the timestamp.

Unfortunately, GNU find's `-printf` doesn't support birth times, so it calls out to `stat(1)` to get those, using the multi-argument version of `-exec` to minimize the number of instances of the program that need to be run. The rest is straightforward sorting of a column, using 0-byte terminators instead of newlines to robustly handle filenames with newlines or other funky characters in them.

Comment: when I run this I only get a `.` (dot) back - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JohnJ Your filesystem might not record birth times (In which case `stat --printf %W` will display 0). Leave out the cut and play with the number of lines returned by head to see if you're getting all 0's for the time.

Comment: (Or even if it's tracked, if on linux, could be using a kernel/glibc version too old to support the `statx()` syscall, or any number of other reasons why the birth time can't be retrieved)

Answer (score 0):

Mantaining a symbolic link to the last known subdirectory could avoid listing all of them to find the latest one.

```
ls -dl $(readlink  ~/tmp/last_dir)
drwxr-xr-x 2 lmc users 4096 Jan 13 13:20 /home/lmc/Documents/some_dir
```

Find newer ones

```
ls -ldt $(find -L . -newer ~/tmp/last_dir -type d ! -path .)
drwxr-xr-x 2 lmc users   6 Mar  1 00:00 ./dir2
drwxr-xr-x 2 lmc users   6 Feb  1 00:00 ./dir1
```

Or

```
ls -ldt $(find -L . -newer ~/tmp/last_dir -type d ! -path .) | head -n 1
drwxr-xr-x 2 lmc users   6 Mar  1 00:00 ./dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use the chosen answer if you really want to find the last created sub-directory

According to the question:

1. Directories should be sorted by creation time instead of modification time.
2. `find --mindepth 1` is necessary because we want to search only sub-directories.

Here are 2 solutions that both fulfill the 2 requirements:

### GNU

```sh
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec stat -c '%W %n' '{}' '+' |
  sort -nr | head -n1
```

### BSD

```sh
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec stat -f '%B %N' '{}' '+' |
  sort -nr | head -n1
```